# A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running

Tags: sql-server, ssas, connectivity

I have 2 PCs at home: Win10 with SQL Server 2016 and Win7 with SQL Server 2014.

Both servers are installed in Windows Authentication mode. I have set up users with the same name on both PCs.

I can connect to Database Engine from Win10 to Win7 and vice versa, but when I try to connect to SSAS, I get following error:

> Cannot connect to XPSWin10.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.
>   (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal.AdomdClient)
>
> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (System)
>
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (System)

I was able to connect to SSAS before I reinstalled my Windows 10 PC.

I should say, I have 2 users in each PC (User10 and User7). On Win10 I login with User10 and on Win7 I login with User7. Both users on both PC have the same password.

The service is running - I can connect locally.

I disabled the firewall and still I have the issue. The only difference is it shows me the error after a minute not immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending lot of time, I found the solution!

As I mentioned, I had to log into Win10 with User10 and at the same time log into Win7, using User7.

Looks like connection was successful when I log into both PC with the same username.

So, I ended up to run SSMS as different user (in each PC) to be able connect to the other one.

On Win10 PC, I created a shortcut to run SSMA as User7, and this way I was able to connect to WIn7 PC and also created the shortcut in Win7 PC to run the SSMS as User10 to be able to connect to Win10 PC.

This link ([FIX Connection](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/03/10/sql-server-fix-a-connection-cannot-be-made-to-redirector-ensure-that-sql-browser-service-is-running-microsoft-analysisservices-adomdclient/)) also might be helpful, it did not help me though.

This is the link to create shortcut to [run as different user](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/164915-run-different-user-shortcut-create-specified-program-user.html)